# Action hook for custom post schedule like publish_future_post

Tags: wordpress

I want to trigger a function in my Wordpress when a scheduled custom post will publish. Unfortunate there is no default action hook for `custom_post_type`.

Here is the sample code of my plugin:

```
function connectwpblog123 () {
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return; 
    $post_status = 'publish';
    $movie_post1 = array();
    $movie_post1['post_title'] = 'Schedule Test Example';
    $movie_post1['post_type']  = 'fbtweets';
    $movie_post1['post_content'] = 'Abce defgh i gk lmno p qr st';
    $movie_post1['post_status'] = $post_status;
    $movie_post1['tags_input'] = array(1);
    $movie_post1['post_category'] = array(1);
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $movie_post1 );
} 
add_action('publish_future_fbtweets', 'connectwpblog123', 10, 1);
```

When I hook my custom post using publish custom post hook:

```
 add_action('publish_post', 'connectwpblog');
```

This triggers the function for infinite time.

Answer (score 1):

To use publish_post with any post type:

```
add_action( 'publish_' . $_POST['post_type'], 'your_func'  );
```